# How to get the month abbreviation instead of number in Razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor, tostring

I have the following code in my MVC 4 razor view, which is supposed to take the **DateTime** property called **modifiedDate**, and print out the month name, i.e., Jan, Feb, etc., instead of 1, 2.

```
@foreach (var post in Model.NewsList)
{
   <li class="entry">
     <p class="calendar"><em>@post.modifiedDate.Value.Month.ToString("mmm")</em></p>               
   </li>
}
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: `@post.modifiedDate.Value.ToString("MMMM")`

Comment: @Romoku that doesn't work either, just prints MMMM.

Comment: Not sure if `modifiedDate` is `DateTime` or `DateTime?`

Comment: @Romoku It's DateTime?

Comment: It should work. Make sure you're not using it on the `Month`.

Comment: Romoku Thanks, that's it fixed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See [The "MMMM" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MMMM_Specifier)

Usage:

```
DateTime? date = DateTime.Now;

date.Value.ToString("MMMM"); // Prints the Month name (e.g. May)
```

Corrected:

```
@foreach (var post in Model.NewsList)
{
   <li class="entry">
     <p class="calendar"><em>@post.modifiedDate.Value.ToString("MMMM")</em></p>               
   </li>
}
```